# Disregarding a line while calculating frequency in python

Tags: python

I have the following format in a text file.

```
-FRFR
YOUAREMYFRIEND
-JKJK
YOUARENOTMYFRIEND
-SSFF
LETUSBEFRIENDS
```

I want to calculate the frequency of each letter in the line that doesn't start with a "-" and it's a huge file so I cannot just copy.

Is there anyway I can do

```
for line in str

if line starts with '-'
      then dont count that line
else:
      do count the line

total_length = 0
nucleotide = {}

seq_file = open("file.txt", "r")
for raw_line in seq_file:
    line = raw_line.rstrip("\r\n")
    length = len(line)
    for nuc in line:
        if nucleotide.has_key(nuc): 
            nucleotide[nuc] += 1
        else:
            nucleotide[nuc] = 1
    total_length += length

seq_file.close()
```

Comment: What's stopping you from running that in Python? Have you tried? Have you seen any specific errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

results = Counter()
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('-'):
            continue

        results.update(line)

print results
```

prints:

```
Counter({'E': 7, 'R': 5, 'N': 4, 'Y': 4, 'D': 3, 'F': 3, 'I': 3, 'O': 3, 'U': 3, 'A': 2, '\n': 2, 'M': 2, 'S': 2, 'T': 2, 'B': 1, 'L': 1})
```

You can also print out n most common items, for example:

```
print results.most_common(3)
```

prints:

```
[('E', 7), ('R', 5), ('N', 4)]
```

Comment: I think your logic would be a little more clear if you negated the ```startswith``` boolean and got rid of ```continue```, so ```if not line.startswith('-'): results.update(line)```, but that's just my opinion

Comment: @wnnmaw yeah, it's debatable on what is more readable, thanks.

Comment: @wnnmaw although I agree in this case, in general I like to test for my fail state and `continue`, then run my code in the loop's block rather than an `if` block inside that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work to test the first character of the line. For example:

```
if (line[0] != '-'): count +=1
```